# inner sep to straighten diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to typeset straight diagrams with tikz. When the nodes are of different sizes, diagrams become "wonky":

[image: wonky]

This can be corrected by forcing all nodes to be the same size with `minimum width` and adjusting the `column sep`. This way we get a straight diagram

[image: straight]

However, now the arrows are too short. I thought this could be fixed by setting `inner sep` (this seems to have solved my problem before), but I can't seem to get it working. How do I make the arrows longer, so they reach the content of the nodes?

Please find a MWE below.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
            {
            & A && B & \\
            extremely long node && D && E \\
            F && G && H \\
            };
        \path[->,line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
            (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2)
            (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
            (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-3-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-3-5) edge (m-2-5)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
Correcting by setting \verb+minimum width = 7em, column sep = -3.5em+
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=-3.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex, minimum width=7.5em, inner sep=3pt]
            {
            & A && B & \\
            extremely long node && D && E \\
            F && G && H \\
            };
        \path[->,line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
            (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2)
            (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
            (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-3-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-3-5) edge (m-2-5)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
Now the arrows are short, even when trying to set \verb+inner sep = 3pt+
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `column sep` and `row sep` fix distance `between borders` of adjacent nodes, but you can change this behavior with `between origins`. This way distance between adjacent nodes is measured with independence from their size.

Important note: write `column sep={3.5em,between origins}` with NO space between `,` and `between`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep={3.5em,between origins}, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
            {
            & A && B & \\
            \text{extremely long node} && D && E \\
            F && G && H \\
            };
        \path[->,line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
            (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2)
            (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
            (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-3-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-3-5) edge (m-2-5)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by just playing a bit with the separation of the offending column. Here I add `-4em` to the separation between the first and second columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3.5em, 
                     text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
               {
            &[-4em] A && B & \\
            extremely long node && D && E \\
            F && G && H \\
            };
        \path[->,line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
            (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2)
            (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
            (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-2-1) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-3-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-3-5) edge (m-2-5)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

A more systematic approach:

- Use `\clap` from package `mathtools` to make the long label zero width
- Use the `calc` tikz library to shorten the arrow from the long label node to D, through `($(m-2-1)+(5em,0)$) edge (m-2-3)`

Here is the code (note that I have also lifted a bit the starting point of the arrow from the long label node to A):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
matrix anchor=m-3-1.north
]
               {
            & A && B & \\
            \clap{extremely long node} & & D && E \\
            F && G && H \\
            };
        \path[->,line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
            ($(m-2-1)+(0,.7em)$) edge (m-1-2)
            (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
            (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            ($(m-2-1)+(5em,0)$) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-3-5)
            (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-3-5) edge (m-2-5)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]